# Correct way to set context in javascript for dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been struggling to set an output context in javascript for a dialogflow webhook and although I've tried numerous examples I've found I get an "Failed to parse" in DialogFlow whatever I try. This is the latest try:

```
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
...
app.intent('YesNo', (conv) => {
  if (numberOfRounds < 5){
    conv.ask("Ny fråga?");
    ++numberOfRounds;
    conv.setContext({
      "name": 'yesnoexpected',
      "lifespan": 1,
      "parameters":{"param": "param value"}
    });
  } else {
```

I'm sure the error is related to the context object because if I remove it then there's no parse error, although functionality of course is not as intended. But where's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the context using a JSON notation, but this is not supported by the actions on google library. If you want to set context in a webhook you should use Javascript objects to do it, like such:

```
conv.contexts.set("ContextName", 5, {contextString: "Value", contextNumber: 1});
```

and then you can the parameters from a previous set context like this:

```
const context = conv.contexts.get("ContextName");
const parameter = context.parameters.contextString;
```

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was looking for. Where can this documentaion be found? It's really hard to find.
The only link I've found was this:
https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_conv_.dialogflowconversation.html

More on an expert level. Also, I really only understand what ContextName is in the example, are 5 supposed to be lifespan and what does the contextNumber stand for?

Comment: Yes, 5 is the lifespan. contextString and contextNumber are examples of how to save variables in the context. contextString is an example that saves a string and contextNumber is an example that saves a number variable.

Comment: Ok. Seems like I need to clear contexts somehow because if i try to set it to another contextname after a while it doesn't seem to be set to the new context anyway. Or maybe there are two context at the same time? The first context is definitely set in javascript using your code example. I could verify that.
Where did you find the documentation for methods like ```context.set?```

Comment: https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_context_.contextvalues.html

Comment: I tried this to get the DialogFlow agent to enter a new intent via context but it doesn't work. Seems like the previous context (yesnoexpected) is still set:
```conv.contexts.delete("yesnoexpected"); 
    conv.contexts.set("timetostop", 1, {contextString: "test", contextNumber: 2}); 
  ```